# Recursive curly braces (\begin(cases))

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need to create a scheme with multiple curly braces inside each other similar to this: [Multiple Curly Braces in Align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587254/multiple-curly-braces-in-align). But i don't need to stretch this braces to their content. Like on the picture:

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: math fonts can not extend `{` in a non symmetric manner with "point" not in the vertical centre, so you'd need to adjust the layout  to do one of (a) centre the { so eg the second one would point above Active, or (b) add more vertical space to allow the centred braces, or (c) do not use a font brace but draw it with `tikz` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could to use the commands `\Edacsac` and `\ShortEdacsac` of the [cascade](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cascade/cascade.pdf) package.

Here a little example that you can complete knowing the syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cascade}


\begin{document}
first
\Edacsac
{second}
{
\Edacsac
{third}
{\ShortEdacsac{over
\ShortEdacsac{smash}{mathrel}}{under}}
{ninenth}
{}
}
{fourth}
{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `bigdelim`. Unfortunately it requires a lot of trial and error, so this is not a systematic solution. But on the other hand, it allows you do some fine-tuning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigdelim,multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{ l @{}l @{}X l @{}X l@{} l @{}X }
   &  &  &  &  &  & \ldelim\{{5}{*}[{\makecell[tl]{Predictive\\~ (extrapo-\\~ lative)}\quad}] & \multirowcell{4}[0pt][l]{First–\\~ second–,etc.\\~ orders of\\~ prediction} \\
   &  &  & \ldelim\{{10}[-7ex]{*}  & \multirowcell{4}[-6ex][l]{Feed-back\\~ (teleo-\\~ logical)}  &  \ldelim\{{8}{*}  &  \\
  \\[4ex]
   & \ldelim\{{9}[-7ex]{*}[Active\quad]  &  \multirow{6}{=}{Purposeful} &  &  &  &   \makecell[tl]{Non-predic-\\~ tive(non-\\~ extrapo-\\~ lative)}  &  \\  
   \ldelim\{{8}[-7ex]{*}[Behavior]  &   &  &  & \makecell[tl]{Non-feed-\\~ back(non-\\~ teleo-\\~ logical)}  &  &    \\  
   &  &  \multirow{2}{=}{Non-purposeful (random)} &  &  &  &    \\[6ex] 
   & \makecell[tl]{Non-\\~ active\\~ (passive)}  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]